# Get different variables from different input fields

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a piece of software that requires the user to enter 2 different things (email and password). The input data needs to be stored in 2 separate variables. One for the email and one for the password. So far I have not been able to achieve this. From what I can tell the only way to use the input data in a variable is by using (inp.get) as a variable. But I can only use this once not twice for separate data.

This is the code I use:

```
class Inputbox():
    def __init__(self, text=""):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.get = ""
        self.root.geometry("300x100")
        self.root.title("ad.lo Dynamics Record builder")
        self.label_file_name = tk.Label(self.root, text=text)
        self.label_file_name.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.focus()
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", lambda x: self.getinput(self.entry.get()))#Get the first input as vairable to use for later

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.entry2.focus()
        self.entry2.bind("<Return>", lambda x: self.getinput(self.entry2.get()))#Get the second input as vairable to use for later

        self.root.mainloop()
 
    def getinput(self, value):
        self.get = value
        self.root.destroy()

inp = Inputbox(text="input password and email")
print(inp.get)#one needs to be the email
print(inp.get)#the other needs to be the password
```

Comment: Well, you need to use two different attributes, not one attribute that both event handlers overwrite.

Comment: What do you mean by that? the self.entry?

Comment: `getinput` always updates `self.get`, regardless of which `Entry` produces its argument.

Comment: So how to I get the 2 different variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tkinter dialogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html):

```py
# Usage may vary by version. Python 3.6+
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog


tk.Tk().withdraw()
email = simpledialog.askstring("Email", "input email:", initialvalue="example@mail.com")
password = simpledialog.askstring("Password", "input password:", show='*')
print(email)
print(password)
```

Or use tk.Entry like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103781/8349697

Answer (score 0):

Your `getinput` method isn't capable of distinguishing between email entry and password entry; it blindly stores values in a single attribute.

You need to distinguish between the two. For example, you can define two separate methods to replace `getinput`, each setting a different attribute.

```
class Inputbox():
    def __init__(self, text=""):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.email = ""
        self.password = ""

        self.root.geometry("300x100")
        self.root.title("ad.lo Dynamics Record builder")
        self.label_file_name = tk.Label(self.root, text=text)
        self.label_file_name.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.focus()
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", lambda x: self.get_email())

        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.entry2.focus()
        self.entry2.bind("<Return>", lambda x:  self.get_password())

        self.root.mainloop()
 
    def get_email(self:
        self.email = self.entry.get()

    def get_password(self):
        self.password = self.entry2.get()

inp = Inputbox(text="input password and email")
print(inp.email)#one needs to be the email
print(inp.password)#the other needs to be the password
```