# Is there is a way to prompt the user for multiple items in a gui using python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, command-prompt

So, I'm trying to prompt the user for multiple variables.

I use this simple gui prompt method, but it only prompts for 1 item at a time, I want to be able to have multiple items in the same gui window. Any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import simpledialog
item = simpledialog.askstring("New Item", "Enter name of item:")
print(item)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get multiple text entries from GUI and use those in a main python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102696/how-to-get-multiple-text-entries-from-gui-and-use-those-in-a-main-python-script)

Comment: It might also be a duplicate of [Correct way to implement a custom popup tkinter dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10057672/7432)